# In Arch linux, do applications launched from a ramdisk act the same if the OS booted from disk vs a liveCD?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, libraries

Let's say our application only tries to access files from it's own directory but it's also based on libraries sitting in /usr/lib, which in turn sits on a disk.  If we set up a ramdisk, move the application to this ramdisk and run it, is it likely to be problematic that the libraries being on the disk will incur slow enough I/O to make the application lag when the libraries are called?

Answer (score 1):

They can, but that's entirely application dependent.  However, since I pointed out that the application in question only tries to access files from it's own directory and calls some libraries, we can assume the only remaining disk traffic will be library calls or OS related.  The threshold of what's acceptable there is up to the user.

To avoid all disk I/O, someone could use an environment that boots entirely to ram.  This can be achieved through the use of initrd.